# Run custom task when call `pip install`

Tags: python, pip, distutils

I want to make my python package "pip installable". The problem is that the package has shell script that must be sourced in the user's init shell script (e.g. `.bashrc`).

But after the installation, the user don't exactly know where the script went (presumably `/usr/bin`, but we can't garantee). Of course the user can runs `which myscript.sh` and manually edits his init script.

But I want to automate this step. I can create a new distutils command, but `pip install` doesn't call it. And I can extend `distutils.command.install.install`, but the installation breaks via pip (although works via `python setup.py install`):

**setup.py**

```
from distutils.command.install import install

class CustomInstall(install):
    def run(self):
        install.run(self)
        # custom stuff here
        do_my_stuff()

setup(..., cmdclass={'install': CustomInstall})
```

**shell**

```
$ pip install dist/mypackage.tar.gz
Unpacking ./dist/mypackage.tar.gz
  Running setup.py egg_info for package from file:///path/to/mypackage/dist/mypackage.tar.gz

Installing collected packages: mypackage
  Running setup.py install for mypackage
    usage: -c [global_opts] cmd1 [cmd1_opts] [cmd2 [cmd2_opts] ...]
       or: -c --help [cmd1 cmd2 ...]
       or: -c --help-commands
       or: -c cmd --help

    error: option --single-version-externally-managed not recognized
    Complete output from command /path/to/.virtualenvs/myvirtualenv/bin/python -c "import setuptools;__file__='/tmp/pip-OFjrqU-build/setup.py';exec(compile(open(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-s4Yo4d-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --install-headers /path/to/.virtualenvs/myvirtualenv/include/site/python2.7:
    usage: -c [global_opts] cmd1 [cmd1_opts] [cmd2 [cmd2_opts] ...]
       or: -c --help [cmd1 cmd2 ...]
       or: -c --help-commands
       or: -c cmd --help

error: option --single-version-externally-managed not recognized

----------------------------------------
Command /path/to/.virtualenvs/myvirtualenv/bin/python -c "import setuptools;__file__='/tmp/pip-OFjrqU-build/setup.py';exec(compile(open(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-s4Yo4d-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --install-headers /path/to/.virtualenvs/myvirtualenv/include/site/python2.7 failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-OFjrqU-build
Storing complete log in /path/to/myhome/.pip/pip.log
```

What is the best aproach to run a custom task after install a package via `pip`?

Comment: Could you try with `from setuptools.command.install import install` instead of using `distutils`?

Comment: @Alok, it worked! please answer so I can accept it. :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Could you try with `from setuptools.command.install import install` instead of using `distutils`?

Comment: Thanks, this really helped me out. I had followed (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17806485/execute-a-python-script-post-install-using-distutils-setuptools) and received the same issue, documented it in (http://blog.diffbrent.com/correctly-adding-nltk-to-your-python-package-using-setup-py-post-install-commands/) and gave you props

Comment: I'm getting the same problem as [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19569557/pip-not-picking-up-a-custom-install-cmdclass?lq=1) - I get the custom behaviour when running `python setup.py install`, but not when I run `pip install <path>`. Any thoughts?

Comment: I have the same issue. ```pip install -e .``` runs the command class and then it runs when I do bdist_wheel but during pip install nothing happens.

Comment: @scubbo did you ever arrive at a solution to this?

Comment: I did not, sorry! This was a while ago, so I'd need to ramp back up to re-understand the issue - hopefully one of the other commenters can help you out, though?

Answer (score 1):

I update the code to work with the

> pip install <path>

as well. In this example, we create a directory structure during installation. All this goes into the setup.py file, followed by `$ pip install .` This solution also answers this related post: [Custom pip install commands not running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36702902/custom-pip-install-commands-not-running)

```
from setuptools import setup
from setuptools.command.install import install
import pip
import os, errno

my_dir_paths = ['1', '2', '3']

class CustomInstall(install):

    def __init__(self, dist):
        super(install, self).__init__(dist)
        self.__current  = "/home/..."
        self.__post_install(self.__current)
        
    def run(self):
        install.run(self)
        
    def __post_install(self, curr):
        try:
            os.makedirs(os.path.join(curr, "data2"))
        except FileExistsError:
            print("Directory %s already exists!"%("data2"))
            pass

        for path in my_dir_paths:
            try:
                os.makedirs(os.path.join(curr, "data2", path))
            except FileExistsError:
                print("Directory %s already exists!"%(path))
                pass



setup(
    name='some_name',
    version='0.1.0',
    author='me',
    author_email='...',
    url='http://...',
    packages=setuptools.find_packages(),
    license='...',
    description='....',
    long_description=open('README.txt').read(),
    install_requires=[
       "pandas >= 1.0.5",
    ],
    python_requires='>=3.6',
    
    cmdclass={'install': CustomInstall}
    
)
```

Comment: Mind to explain what is `dist` here? Does it support `pip` from `pypi`?

Comment: replace dist with *args if that helps (less specific). The ```setuptools.command.install``` did not work for me without it.