# Pip not picking up a custom install cmdclass

Tags: python, pip

so I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15853058/run-custom-task-when-call-pip-install)
to my exact question, but for some reason it's not working:

`$ cat /tmp/testinstall/setup.py`:

```
from setuptools.command.install import install

from setuptools import setup


class verifying_install(install):
    def run(self):
        print "running........"
        install.run(self)
        print "verifying........"


setup(name='test',
      version='1',
      py_modules=['test'],
      include_package_data=True,
      zip_safe=True,
      cmdclass={'install': verifying_install}
)
```

But then, even though `setup.py install` works::

```
➜  /tmp/testinstall
$ mktmpenv && cd -
This is a temporary environment. It will be deleted when you run 'deactivate'.

(5bc7db7ca1b34ec5)➜  /tmp/testinstall
$ python setup.py install
running install
running........
running build
running build_py
creating build
creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7
copying test.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7
running egg_info
creating test.egg-info
writing test.egg-info/PKG-INFO
writing top-level names to test.egg-info/top_level.txt
writing dependency_links to test.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
writing manifest file 'test.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
reading manifest file 'test.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
writing manifest file 'test.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
running install_lib
copying build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/test.py -> /home/bwm/.virtualenvs/5bc7db7ca1b34ec5/lib/python2.7/site-packages
byte-compiling /home/bwm/.virtualenvs/5bc7db7ca1b34ec5/lib/python2.7/site-packages/test.py to test.pyc
running install_egg_info
Copying test.egg-info to /home/bwm/.virtualenvs/5bc7db7ca1b34ec5/lib/python2.7/site-packages/test-1-py2.7.egg-info
running install_scripts
verifying........
```

(Note the `running...` and `verifying......` lines)

`pip install` of the directory doesn't work:

```
(5bc7db7ca1b34ec5)➜  /tmp/testinstall
$ deactivate && mktmpenv && cd - && pip install .
Removing temporary environment: 5bc7db7ca1b34ec5
Removing 5bc7db7ca1b34ec5...
New python executable in 4cac61c13d080257/bin/python
Installing Setuptools...done.
Installing Pip....done.
This is a temporary environment. It will be deleted when you run 'deactivate'.
/tmp/testinstall
Unpacking /tmp/testinstall
  Running setup.py egg_info for package from file:///tmp/testinstall

Cleaning up...
```

And pip install of the sdist doesn't work either:

```
(4cac61c13d080257)➜  /tmp/testinstall
$ python setup.py sdist
running sdist
# ..snip..
creating dist
Creating tar archive
removing 'test-1' (and everything under it)
(4cac61c13d080257)➜  /tmp/testinstall
$ deactivate && mktmpenv && cd -
Removing temporary environment: 4cac61c13d080257
Removing 4cac61c13d080257...
New python executable in 9a42f3a58809f1a3/bin/python
Installing Setuptools...done.
Installing Pip...done.
This is a temporary environment. It will be deleted when you run 'deactivate'.
/tmp/testinstall

(9a42f3a58809f1a3)➜  /tmp/testinstall
$ ls dist
test-1.tar.gz
(9a42f3a58809f1a3)➜  /tmp/testinstall
$ pip install dist/test-1.tar.gz
Unpacking ./dist/test-1.tar.gz
  Running setup.py egg_info for package from file:///tmp/testinstall/dist/test-1.tar.gz

Cleaning up...
```

Note the lack of `running...` and `verifying...` words in both of those.

Anybody have any idea what's going on here?

Answer (score 22):

I ran into this problem just now. It looks like there are many different commands that `pip install my-package` can translate into.

1. `setup.py install`
2. `setup.py egg_info`
3. `setup.py develop`

So you need to handle each of these different cases.

```
from setuptools.command.install import install
from setuptools.command.develop import develop
from setuptools.command.egg_info import egg_info

'''
BEGIN CUSTOM INSTALL COMMANDS
These classes are used to hook into setup.py's install process. Depending on the context:
$ pip install my-package

Can yield `setup.py install`, `setup.py egg_info`, or `setup.py develop`
'''


def custom_command():
    import sys
    if sys.platform in ['darwin', 'linux']:
        os.system('./custom_command.sh')


class CustomInstallCommand(install):
    def run(self):
        install.run(self)
        custom_command()


class CustomDevelopCommand(develop):
    def run(self):
        develop.run(self)
        custom_command()


class CustomEggInfoCommand(egg_info):
    def run(self):
        egg_info.run(self)
        custom_command()

'''
END CUSTOM INSTALL COMMANDS 
'''

setup(
    ...
    cmdclass={
        'install': CustomInstallCommand,
        'develop': CustomDevelopCommand,
        'egg_info': CustomEggInfoCommand,
    },
    ...
)
```

Comment: I have tried this, but it does not work when trying to install the sdist package from pypi. See related discussion https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150536/discussion-between-swiftsnamesake-and-collins-a . Only local installs and installation directly from git repository seems to work.

Comment: Did you finally found any solution to this issue? I'm facing same

Answer (score 13):

I ran into the same problem. Try running `pip install -vvv <path>` - it may be that the messages are being hidden somehow (I don't know why - not a pip expert!). In any case, you can confirm that the code is being run by having your custom code print to a file somewhere instead of to STDOUT.

Comment: I can't find the SO question which I saw this on, but it may be intentional; `pip` silences the output of `setup.py` https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/2732#issuecomment-97119093

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
pip install dist/test-1.tar.gz -U
```