# Custom post install script not running with pip

Tags: python, python-3.x, setuptools, distutils, python-packaging

> **Please** before flagging as duplicate, I have tried a bunch of solutions
>   including one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15853058/run-custom-task-when-call-pip-install)
>   but no luck

I have created a simple tool to do some tasks and was able to package it successfully.

When trying to install it, I get the desired effect when I use `python setup.py install` but `pip install package_name` just installs the package but no post installation script.

Here is part of my code;

**setup.py**

```
from distutils import setup
from app.scripts import *

setup(

        #Application name
        name = "my-app-name",

        version = "my-app-version",
        author = "my-name",
        author_email = "my-email",
        packages = ['app'],
        include_package_data = True,
        license = 'MIT',
        url = "https://my-url",
        description = "description",
        install_requires = ["flake8"],
        cmdclass = {
            "install":Post_install
        }
    )
```

**scripts.py**

```
from distutils.command.install import install
import os

class Post_install(install):

    @staticmethod
    def func():      
        return True

    def run(self):
        install.run(self)
        #Pre install actions
        if Post_install.func():
            print("Bingo")
        else:
            print("Failed")
```

Thanks :)

**PS** I run `pip install` after uploading the package.

Comment: Is it possible that you're installing an earlier version of your library? Does it take a while for the pip servers to update?

Comment: It's hard to tell since you've stripped the code of certain details.

Comment: @SwiftsNamesake I have verified the version of the library I'm installing, it is the right one, I'm sure of that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install the package directly from your GitHub repository:

```
pip install -vvv git+url/for/github/repo@my-branch
```

You mentioned in the [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150536/discussion-between-swiftsnamesake-and-collins-a) that you'd like to add this package to your `requirements.txt` file. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16584552/how-to-state-in-requirements-txt-a-direct-github-source) for details:

```
-e git://github.com/path/to/project
```

---

**Former answer (rejected by the OP):**

I managed to recreate the issue you're having. It seems to be a matter of `pip install` silencing or redirecting output (as indicated by an answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19569557/pip-not-picking-up-a-custom-install-cmdclass)).

The solution is to add the option `-vvv` after `pip install`. I'm guessing the *v* stands for *verbose*.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I've also tried all those proposed options and it seems not to work with pip, "though working fine with `python setup.py install`

Comment: To be clear, you're saying that `pip install -vvv [name of package]` doesn't work? If so, that's really odd, since I copied your files and tried it myself on a local dummy package (`pip install -vvv .`).

Comment: It installs the package, but post install script still not running

Comment: Yeah local install with `setup.py install` also works fine " as I wrote in question", But `pip` oddly doesn't run the post install scripts

Comment: I meant a local pip install

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150536/discussion-between-swiftsnamesake-and-collins-a).