# Running custom code with pip install fails

Tags: python, pip, setuptools

I have a Python package that I'm distributing with pip.  I need to add some custom code to be run at install time:

```
from setuptools import setup                                                        

from setuptools.command.install import install                                      

class CustomInstall(install):                                                       
    def run(self):                                                                  
        install.run(self)                                                           
        print "TEST"                                                           

setup(                                                                              
      ...                                      
      cmdclass={'install': CustomInstall},
      ...)
```

I thought the problem might pip suppressing stdout: [Custom pip install commands not running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36702902/custom-pip-install-commands-not-running).  But then I replaced `print "TEST"` with creating a file and writing some text, and that didn't happen either.

It appears that my custom run method is only happening when I create and upload my_package to test PyPI:

```
python setup.py sdist bdist_wheel upload -r https://testpypi.python.org/pypi
```

and not when I pip install it:

```
pip install -i https://testpypi.python.org/pypi my_package
```

Maybe I am fundamentally not understanding how pip and setuptools work, but that is the opposite of the behavior I expected.

My questions are:

1. How can I get my CustomInstall class to work?

and

2. What actually happens when you call `pip install`?

I've looked a the setuptools docs and the PyPI docs, and I haven't been able to figure it out.  It seems like other people have had success with this:  [Run custom task when call `pip install`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15853058/run-custom-task-when-call-pip-install), so I'm not sure what's going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

So I'm not sure how much this will help, but I recently dealt with a similar issue, and here's what I learned.

1. Your custom install code appears to be correct.  However, there are more methods than just `run` that can be overridden. Another useful one is `finalize_options` because you can write code to dynamically change the parameters of your `setup.py` (example [here](https://github.com/pexip/os-walinuxagent/blob/78949502fd9424fe9685da5b1b110431ee8bddbe/setup.py#L202).)
2. This is a very good question to ask.`pip install` does various things depending on various factors. From where are you installing the package? From PyPI or some other package index? How was the package distributed? Is it a binary dist (.whl) or a source dist (.gz) file? Are you installing the package via a local directory? A remote repo via a VCS URL? Pip does not necessarily use the same approach for each of these cases. I would recommend using the `-vvv` flag to see what exactly pip is doing. It may not be running setuptools's `install` command for whatever reason...do you have

   ```
    packages=setuptools.find_packages(),
    include_package_data=True
   ```

in your `setup.py` file? Without these lines, pip could be installing your package's metadata but not the package itself.