# Running post install code from PyPi via pip

Tags: python, pip, setuptools, pypi

I am trying to run a block of code after my python package has been downloaded from PyPi.

I've setup a custom `cmdclass` in my `setuptools.setup`

```
from setuptools import find_packages, setup
from setuptools.command.install import install


class CustomInstallCommand(install):
    def run(self):
        print "Here is where I would be running my code..."
        install.run(self)



setup(
  name = 'packagename',
  packages=find_packages(),
  version = '0.1',
  description = '',
  author = '',
  cmdclass={
    'install': CustomInstallCommand,
  },
  author_email = '',
  url = '',
  keywords = [],
  classifiers = [],
)
```

This works great when I run `python setup.py install` which outputs my print statement. However, when I build the tar.gz package (using `python setup.py sdist`) and try to install via pip (`pip install dist/mypackage-0.1.tar.gz`), the print statement is never printed. I have also tried to upload the built package to PyPi and pip install from there.

I have looked at a similar question [asked on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15853058/run-custom-task-when-call-pip-install) but the solution did not work.

Comment: Have you tried raising the verbosity level using `pip install -v ...`?

Comment: @NilsWerner Oh I suppose it was there all along, but being suppressed to stdout. So even though it's not displayed from pip, it's still being ran?

Comment: Yup. pip just hides all output if there wasn't an error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`pip install` does run your custom command, it just hides all standard output from `setup.py`. To increase verbosity level and see your command output, try running

```
pip install -v ...
```