# Python setuptools/distutils custom build for the `extra` package with Makefile

Tags: python, makefile, python-packaging, python-install

**Preamble:**
Python setuptools are used for the package distribution. I have a Python package (let us call it `my_package`), that has several `extra_require` packages to it. Everything works just find (installation and build of the package, as well as extras, if were requested), as all `extra_require` were python packages themselves and pip correctly resolved everything. A simple `pip install my_package` worked like a charm.

**Setup:** 
Now, for one of the extras (let us call it `extra1`) I need to call a binary of a non-python library `X`.

Module `X` itself (source code) was added to the `my_package` codebase and was included in the distribution `my_package`. Sadly for me, to be utilized, `X` needs to be compiled first into a binary on the target machine (C++ implementation; I assume such compilation shall happen on the build stage of `my_package` installation). There is a `Makefile` in the `X` library optimized for different platform compilation, so all that is needed, is to run `make` in the respective directory of `X` library in the `my_package` when the build process is running.

*Question #1*: how to run a terminal command (i.e., `make` in my case) during the build process of the package, using setuptools/distutils?

*Question #2*: how to ensure, that such terminal command is executed only if the corresponding `extra1` is specified during the installation process?

Example:

1. If someone runs `pip install my_package`, no such additional compilation of library `X` shall happen.
2. If someone runs `pip install my_package [extra1]`, module `X` needs to be compiled, so the corresponding binary would be created and available on the target machine.

Comment: Posible duplicate of [How can I run a Makefile in setup.py](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1754966/how-can-i-run-a-makefile-in-setup-py)?

Comment: Not exactly. It a) doesn't have the answer for a situation, when such installation is required, only when the "extra1" is involved. b) It is not really informative/detailed. I would appreciate a more detailed answer, and I believe this is would be very informative for the community if a rather detailed answer was provided.

Comment: Does `X` have a `setup.py` and thus is a regular Python package?

Comment: No, `X` is cpp package with a Makefile. Makefile itself is very flexible and supports multiple platforms. So all that needs to be done, is a single 'make' in the corresponding subfolder.

Comment: It can be done, but it's hard. I'd recommend handling `X` as a non-Python dependency, not installable using `pip`. I.e. you (and your users) would have to install `X` using the OS package manager or manually. Note that you cannot even hope for a decent `make` on all platforms.

Comment: I will keep that in mind. My idea now will be as follows: try to find an automatic solution with respect to the question I've posted, and also have a backup plan, so that I can resort to the end user installing package `X` separately.

Comment: Can you compile the binary and distribute a your project as a wheel rather than (or in addition to) the source package?

Answer (score 15):

This question came back to haunt me long after I commented on it two years ago! I had almost the same problem myself recently, and I found the documentation VERY scarce, as I think most of you must have experienced. So I tried to research a bit of the source code of [setuptools](https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/tree/master/setuptools) and [distutils](https://github.com/python/cpython/tree/6f0eb93183519024cb360162bdd81b9faec97ba6/Lib/distutils) to see if I could find a more or less standard approach to both the questions you asked.

---

The first question you asked

> *Question #1*: how to run a terminal command (i.e., `make` in my case) during the build process of the package, using setuptools/distutils?

has many approaches and all of them involve setting a `cmdclass` when calling `setup`. The parameter `cmdclass` of `setup` must be a mapping between command names that will execute depending on the build or install needs of the distribution, and classes that inherit from [`distutils.cmd.Command`](https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/apiref.html#module-distutils.cmd) base class (as a side note, the `setuptools.command.Command` class is derived from `distutils`' `Command` class so you can derive directly from `setuptools` implementation).

The `cmdclass` allows you to define any command name, like what [ayoon](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43013234/7253166) did and then execute it specifically when calling `python setup.py --install-option="customcommand"` from the command line. The problem with this, is that it is not the standard command that will be executed when trying to install a package through `pip` or by calling `python setup.py install`. The standard way to approach this is to check what commands will `setup` try to execute in a normal install and then overload that particular `cmdclass`.

From looking into [`setuptools.setup`](https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/blob/bb71fd1bed9f5e5e239ef99be82ed57e9f9b1dda/setuptools/__init__.py#L126) and [`distutils.setup`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/6f0eb93183519024cb360162bdd81b9faec97ba6/Lib/distutils/core.py), `setup` will run the commands it [found in the command line](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/6f0eb93183519024cb360162bdd81b9faec97ba6/Lib/distutils/core.py#L145:L148), which lets assume is just a plain `install`. In the case of `setuptools.setup`, this will trigger a series of tests that will see whether to resort to a simple call to the `distutils.install` command class, and if this does not occur, it will attempt to run [`bdist_egg`](https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/blob/master/setuptools/command/install.py#L109). In turn, this command does many things but crucially decides on whether to call the `build_clib`, `build_py` and/or the `build_ext` commands. The `distutils.install` simply runs `build` if necessary which also runs [`build_clib`](https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/blob/master/setuptools/command/build_clib.py), [`build_py`](https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/blob/master/setuptools/command/build_py.py) and/or [`build_ext`](https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/blob/master/setuptools/command/build_ext.py). This means that regardless of whether you use `setuptools` or `distutils`, if it is necessary to build from source, the commands [`build_clib`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/6f0eb93183519024cb360162bdd81b9faec97ba6/Lib/distutils/command/build_clib.py), [`build_py`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/6f0eb93183519024cb360162bdd81b9faec97ba6/Lib/distutils/command/build_py.py), and/or [`build_ext`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/6f0eb93183519024cb360162bdd81b9faec97ba6/Lib/distutils/command/build_ext.py) will be runned, so these are the ones that we will want to overload with the `cmdclass` of `setup`, the question becomes which of the three.

- `build_py` is used to "build" pure python packages, so we can safely ignore it.
- `build_ext` is used to build declared Extension modules that are passed through the `ext_modules` parameter of the call to the `setup` function. If we wish to overload this class, the main method that builds each extension is [`build_extension`](https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/blob/master/setuptools/command/build_ext.py#L190) (or [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/6f0eb93183519024cb360162bdd81b9faec97ba6/Lib/distutils/command/build_ext.py#L485) for distutils)
- `build_clib` is used to build declared libraries that are passed through the `libraries` parameter of the call to the `setup` function. In this case, the main method that we should overload with our derived class is the [`build_libraries`](https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/blob/master/setuptools/command/build_clib.py#L23) method ([here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/6f0eb93183519024cb360162bdd81b9faec97ba6/Lib/distutils/command/build_clib.py#L181) for `distutils`).

I'll share an example package that builds a toy c static library through a Makefile by using `setuptools` `build_ext` command. The approach can be adapted to using the `build_clib` command, but you'll have to checkout the source code of `build_clib.build_libraries`.

**setup.py**

```
import os, subprocess
import setuptools
from setuptools.command.build_ext import build_ext
from distutils.errors import DistutilsSetupError
from distutils import log as distutils_logger


extension1 = setuptools.extension.Extension('test_pack_opt.test_ext',
                    sources = ['test_pack_opt/src/test.c'],
                    libraries = [':libtestlib.a'],
                    library_dirs = ['test_pack_opt/lib/'],
                    )

class specialized_build_ext(build_ext, object):
    """
    Specialized builder for testlib library

    """
    special_extension = extension1.name

    def build_extension(self, ext):

        if ext.name!=self.special_extension:
            # Handle unspecial extensions with the parent class' method
            super(specialized_build_ext, self).build_extension(ext)
        else:
            # Handle special extension
            sources = ext.sources
            if sources is None or not isinstance(sources, (list, tuple)):
                raise DistutilsSetupError(
                       "in 'ext_modules' option (extension '%s'), "
                       "'sources' must be present and must be "
                       "a list of source filenames" % ext.name)
            sources = list(sources)

            if len(sources)>1:
                sources_path = os.path.commonpath(sources)
            else:
                sources_path = os.path.dirname(sources[0])
            sources_path = os.path.realpath(sources_path)
            if not sources_path.endswith(os.path.sep):
                sources_path+= os.path.sep

            if not os.path.exists(sources_path) or not os.path.isdir(sources_path):
                raise DistutilsSetupError(
                       "in 'extensions' option (extension '%s'), "
                       "the supplied 'sources' base dir "
                       "must exist" % ext.name)

            output_dir = os.path.realpath(os.path.join(sources_path,'..','lib'))
            if not os.path.exists(output_dir):
                os.makedirs(output_dir)

            output_lib = 'libtestlib.a'

            distutils_logger.info('Will execute the following command in with subprocess.Popen: \n{0}'.format(
                  'make static && mv {0} {1}'.format(output_lib, os.path.join(output_dir, output_lib))))


            make_process = subprocess.Popen('make static && mv {0} {1}'.format(output_lib, os.path.join(output_dir, output_lib)),
                                            cwd=sources_path,
                                            stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                                            stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
                                            shell=True)
            stdout, stderr = make_process.communicate()
            distutils_logger.debug(stdout)
            if stderr:
                raise DistutilsSetupError('An ERROR occured while running the '
                                          'Makefile for the {0} library. '
                                          'Error status: {1}'.format(output_lib, stderr))
            # After making the library build the c library's python interface with the parent build_extension method
            super(specialized_build_ext, self).build_extension(ext)


setuptools.setup(name = 'tester',
       version = '1.0',
       ext_modules = [extension1],
       packages = ['test_pack', 'test_pack_opt'],
       cmdclass = {'build_ext': specialized_build_ext},
       )
```

**test_pack/__init__.py**

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, print_function

def py_test_fun():
    print('Hello from python test_fun')

try:
    from test_pack_opt.test_ext import test_fun as c_test_fun
    test_fun = c_test_fun
except ImportError:
    test_fun = py_test_fun
```

**test_pack_opt/__init__.py**

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, print_function
import test_pack_opt.test_ext
```

**test_pack_opt/src/Makefile**

```
LIBS =  testlib.so testlib.a
SRCS =  testlib.c
OBJS =  testlib.o
CFLAGS = -O3 -fPIC
CC = gcc
LD = gcc
LDFLAGS =

all: shared static

shared: libtestlib.so

static: libtestlib.a

libtestlib.so: $(OBJS)
    $(LD) -pthread -shared $(OBJS) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@

libtestlib.a: $(OBJS)
    ar crs $@ $(OBJS) $(LDFLAGS)

clean: cleantemp
    rm -f $(LIBS)

cleantemp:
    rm -f $(OBJS)  *.mod

.SUFFIXES: $(SUFFIXES) .c

%.o:%.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $<
```

**test_pack_opt/src/test.c**

```
#include <Python.h>
#include "testlib.h"

static PyObject*
test_ext_mod_test_fun(PyObject* self, PyObject* args, PyObject* keywds){
    testlib_fun();
    return Py_None;
}

static PyMethodDef TestExtMethods[] = {
    {"test_fun", (PyCFunction) test_ext_mod_test_fun, METH_VARARGS | METH_KEYWORDS, "Calls function in shared library"},
    {NULL, NULL, 0, NULL}
};

#if PY_VERSION_HEX >= 0x03000000
    static struct PyModuleDef moduledef = {
        PyModuleDef_HEAD_INIT,
        "test_ext",
        NULL,
        -1,
        TestExtMethods,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        NULL
    };

    PyMODINIT_FUNC
    PyInit_test_ext(void)
    {
        PyObject *m = PyModule_Create(&moduledef);
        if (!m) {
            return NULL;
        }
        return m;
    }
#else
    PyMODINIT_FUNC
    inittest_ext(void)
    {
        PyObject *m = Py_InitModule("test_ext", TestExtMethods);
        if (m == NULL)
        {
            return;
        }
    }
#endif
```

**test_pack_opt/src/testlib.c**

```
#include "testlib.h"

void testlib_fun(void){
    printf("Hello from testlib_fun!\n");
}
```

**test_pack_opt/src/testlib.h**

```
#ifndef TESTLIB_H
#define TESTLIB_H

#include <stdio.h>

void testlib_fun(void);

#endif
```

In this example, the c library that I want to build using the custom Makefile just has one function which prints `"Hello from testlib_fun!\n"` to stdout. The `test.c` script is a simple interface between python and this library's single function. The idea is that I tell `setup` that I want to build a c extension named `test_pack_opt.test_ext`, which only has a single source file: the `test.c` interface script, and I also tell the extension that it must link against the static library `libtestlib.a`. The main thing is that I overload the `build_ext` cmdclass using `specialized_build_ext(build_ext, object)`. The inheritance from `object` is only necessary if you want to be able to call `super` to dispatch to parent class methods. The `build_extension` method takes an `Extension` instance as its second argument, in order to work nice with other `Extension` instances that require the default behavior of `build_extension`, I check if this extension has the name of the special one and if it doesn't I call the `super`'s `build_extension` method.

For the special library, I call the Makefile simply with `subprocess.Popen('make static ...')`. The rest of the command passed to the shell is just to move the static library to a certain default location in which the library should be found to be able to link it to the rest of the compiled extension (which is also just compiled using the `super`'s `build_extension` method).

As you can imagine there are just sooo many ways in which you could organize this code differently, it does not make sense to list them all. I hope this example serves to illustrate how to call the Makefile, and which `cmdclass` and `Command` derived class you should overload to call `make` in a standard installation.

---

Now, onto question 2.

> *Question #2*: how to ensure, that such terminal command is executed only if the corresponding extra1 is specified during the installation process?

This was possible with the deprecated `features` parameter of `setuptools.setup`. The standard way is to try to install the package depending on the requirements that are met. `install_requires` lists the mandatory requirements, the `extras_requires` lists the optional requirements. For example from the [`setuptools` documentation](http://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#declaring-extras-optional-features-with-their-own-dependencies)

```
setup(
    name="Project-A",
    ...
    extras_require={
        'PDF':  ["ReportLab>=1.2", "RXP"],
        'reST': ["docutils>=0.3"],
    }
)
```

you could force the installation of the optional required packages by calling `pip install Project-A[PDF]`, but if for some reason the requirements for the `'PDF'` named extra were satisfied before hand, `pip install Project-A` would end up with the same `"Project-A"` functionality. This means that the way in which "Project-A" is installed is not customized for each extra specified at the command line, "Project-A" will always try to install in the same way and may end up with reduced functionality because of unavailable optional requirements.

From what I understood, this means that in order to get your module X to be compiled and installed only if [extra1] is specified, you should ship module X as a separate package and depend on it through an `extras_require`. Lets imagine module X will be shipped in `my_package_opt`, your setup for `my_package` should look like

```
setup(
    name="my_package",
    ...
    extras_require={
        'extra1':  ["my_package_opt"],
    }
)
```

---

Well, I'm sorry that my answer ended up being so long but I hope it helps. Don't hesitate in pointing out any conceptual or naming error, as I mostly tried to deduce this from the `setuptools` source code.

Comment: `sources_path = os.path.commonprefix(sources)`

Should this line call `os.path.commonpath` instead? `commonprefix` does not necessarily return a valid path, just a string prefix. For example, `os.path.commonprefix(["/existing1", "/existing2"]) == "/existing"`.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, the docs are extremely scarce around the interaction between setup.py and pip, but you should be able to do something like this:

```
import subprocess

from setuptools import Command
from setuptools import setup


class CustomInstall(Command):

    user_options = []

    def initialize_options(self):
        pass

    def finalize_options(self):
        pass

    def run(self):
        subprocess.call(
            ['touch',
             '/home/{{YOUR_USERNAME}}/'
             'and_thats_why_you_should_never_run_pip_as_sudo']
        )

setup(
    name='hack',
    version='0.1',
    cmdclass={'customcommand': CustomInstall}
)
```

This gives you a hook into running arbitrary code with commands, and also supports a variety of custom option parsing (not demonstrated here).

Put this in a `setup.py` file and try this:

`pip install --install-option="customcommand" .`

Note that this command is executed *after* the main install sequence, so depending on exactly what you're trying to do, it may not work. See the verbose pip install output:

```
(.venv) ayoon:tmp$ pip install -vvv --install-option="customcommand" .
/home/ayoon/tmp/.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py:194: UserWarning: Disabling all use of wheels due to the use of --build-options / -
-global-options / --install-options.                                                                                                                        
  cmdoptions.check_install_build_global(options)
Processing /home/ayoon/tmp
  Running setup.py (path:/tmp/pip-j57ovc7i-build/setup.py) egg_info for package from file:///home/ayoon/tmp
    Running command python setup.py egg_info
    running egg_info
    creating pip-egg-info/hack.egg-info
    writing pip-egg-info/hack.egg-info/PKG-INFO
    writing dependency_links to pip-egg-info/hack.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
    writing top-level names to pip-egg-info/hack.egg-info/top_level.txt
    writing manifest file 'pip-egg-info/hack.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
    reading manifest file 'pip-egg-info/hack.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
    writing manifest file 'pip-egg-info/hack.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
  Source in /tmp/pip-j57ovc7i-build has version 0.1, which satisfies requirement hack==0.1 from file:///home/ayoon/tmp
Could not parse version from link: file:///home/ayoon/tmp
Installing collected packages: hack
  Running setup.py install for hack ...     Running command /home/ayoon/tmp/.venv/bin/python3.6 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-j57ovc7
i-build/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --
record /tmp/pip-_8hbltc6-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/ayoon/tmp/.venv/include/site/python3
.6/hack customcommand                                                                                                                                       
    running install
    running build
    running install_egg_info
    running egg_info
    writing hack.egg-info/PKG-INFO
    writing dependency_links to hack.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
    writing top-level names to hack.egg-info/top_level.txt
    reading manifest file 'hack.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
    writing manifest file 'hack.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
    Copying hack.egg-info to /home/ayoon/tmp/.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/hack-0.1-py3.6.egg-info
    running install_scripts
    writing list of installed files to '/tmp/pip-_8hbltc6-record/install-record.txt'
    running customcommand
done
  Removing source in /tmp/pip-j57ovc7i-build
Successfully installed hack-0.1
```