# Python setuptools: first build from sources then install

Tags: python, python-3.x, blender, setuptools, pypi

I am having some trouble understanding some of the basic paradigms around setuptools and am hoping to get some help understanding some of the principals and options surrounding setuptools for python.

Currently, I am working on a cross platform implementation of the blender as a python module build cycle, such that bpy.pyd/ bpy.so could be installed from pip.

I am successfully able to perform this build process from Windows. You can check out the repo here: https://github.com/TylerGubala/blenderpy

My primary concerns are as follows:

1) I have supplementary files to facilitate building for different system architectures; I want to upload **these** to pypi, not the built binaries

2) The supplementary files should not live inside the package when it is installed, they are only relevant during the setup/ build process

3) Currently, the way that the setup script works, is that it builds the modules, then sneakily copies the built files into the site-packages and executable directory for the given python environment. My concern here is: how, when the user runs `py -m pip uninstall blenderpy` will the package manager know to grab these files and remove them?

4) What is the correct way to package such a module as this?

I think my primary disconnect is coming from the fact that I would be using pypi as a build script delivery system, where the actual module that I intend to install is not present until midway through the setup.py execution.

So how could I install these utilities onto a user's machine, run them, and have my resultant built bpy.pyd be the source for my package?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: I feel I should mention that I read through the following post and, while it seems related it seems to be talking more about 'extras' handlers and the internals of setuptools rather than talking about installing a compiled library that's controlled by python build scripts.

[Python setuptools/distutils custom build for the `extra` package with Makefile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41169711/python-setuptools-distutils-custom-build-for-the-extra-package-with-makefile)

Comment: I recently read more on setuptools, I'm going to try to use a combination of setuptools.commands.install and the setup_requires package options to resolve my issue.

Comment: I am successfully able to manually build and place my files into site-packages. You can test my solution (hopefully) in a venv by doing `pip install bpy`. I did this through the use of a custom command subclassing `setuptools.commands.install`. Unfortunately my fears were confirmed when `pip uninstall bpy` reported: "Skipping module bpy, it is not installed". How to specify the package and installed package files for uninstallation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UPDATED 28th July, 2018 for multiple improvements that I found.

I ended up finding through a lot of research and a **lot** of trial-and-error what I needed to do to accomplish my goal.

In the end, the solution ended up looking almost exactly like what hoefling over at this question ended up doing:

[Extending setuptools extension to use CMake in setup.py?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42585210/extending-setuptools-extension-to-use-cmake-in-setup-py)

1) Extend the `setuptools.Extension` class with a class of my own, which does not contain entries for the `sources` or `libs` properties

2) Extend the `setuptools.commands.build_ext.build_ext` class with a class of my own, which has a custom method which performs my necessary build steps (git, svn, cmake, cmake --build)

3) Extend the `distutils.command.install_data.install_data` class (*yuck*, distutils... however there doesn't seem to be a setuputils equivalent) with a class of my own, to mark the built binary libraries during setuptools' record creation (installed-files.txt) such that

- The libraries will be recorded and will be uninstalled with `pip uninstall bpy`
- The command `py setup.py bdist_wheel` will work natively as well, and can be used to provide precompiled versions of your source code

4) Extend the `setuptools.command.install_lib.install_lib` class with a class of my own, which will ensure that the built libraries are moved from their resultant build folder into the folder that setuptools expects them in (on Windows it will put the .dll files in a bin/Release folder and not where setuptools expects it)

5) Extend the `setuptools.command.install_scripts.install_scripts` class with a class of my own such that the scripts files are copied to the correct directory (Blender expects the 2.79 or whatever directory to be in the scripts location)

6) After the build steps are performed, copy those files into a known directory that setuptools will copy into the `site-packages` directory of my environment. At this point the remaining setuptools and distutils classes can take over writing the installed-files.txt record and will be fully removable!

You can check out the up to date repository here: https://github.com/TylerGubala/blenderpy

Here is a snapshot of what I ended up with:

```
"""
Build blender into a python module
"""

from distutils.command.install_data import install_data
import os
import pathlib
from setuptools import find_packages, setup, Extension
from setuptools.command.build_ext import build_ext
from setuptools.command.install_lib import install_lib
from setuptools.command.install_scripts import install_scripts
import shutil
import struct
import sys
from typing import List

PYTHON_EXE_DIR = os.path.dirname(sys.executable)

BLENDER_GIT_REPO_URL = 'git://git.blender.org/blender.git'
BLENDERPY_DIR = os.path.join(pathlib.Path.home(), ".blenderpy")

BITS = struct.calcsize("P") * 8

LINUX_BLENDER_BUILD_DEPENDENCIES = ['build-essential']

LINUX_BLENDER_ADDTL_DEPENDENCIES = ['libfreetype6-dev', 'libglew-dev',
                                    'libglu1-mesa-dev', 'libjpeg-dev',
                                    'libpng12-dev', 'libsndfile1-dev',
                                    'libx11-dev', 'libxi-dev',
                                    # How to find current Python version best 
                                    # guess and install the right one?
                                    'python3.5-dev',
                                    # TODO: Update the above for a more 
                                    # maintainable way of getting correct 
                                    # Python version
                                    'libalut-dev', 'libavcodec-dev', 
                                    'libavdevice-dev', 'libavformat-dev', 
                                    'libavutil-dev', 'libfftw3-dev',
                                    'libjack-dev', 'libmp3lame-dev',
                                    'libopenal-dev', 'libopenexr-dev',
                                    'libopenjpeg-dev', 'libsdl1.2-dev',
                                    'libswscale-dev', 'libtheora-dev',
                                    'libtiff5-dev', 'libvorbis-dev',
                                    'libx264-dev', 'libspnav-dev']

class CMakeExtension(Extension):
    """
    An extension to run the cmake build
    """

    def __init__(self, name, sources=[]):

        super().__init__(name = name, sources = sources)

class InstallCMakeLibsData(install_data):
    """
    Just a wrapper to get the install data into the egg-info
    """

    def run(self):
        """
        Outfiles are the libraries that were built using cmake
        """

        # There seems to be no other way to do this; I tried listing the
        # libraries during the execution of the InstallCMakeLibs.run() but
        # setuptools never tracked them, seems like setuptools wants to
        # track the libraries through package data more than anything...
        # help would be appriciated

        self.outfiles = self.distribution.data_files

class InstallCMakeLibs(install_lib):
    """
    Get the libraries from the parent distribution, use those as the outfiles

    Skip building anything; everything is already built, forward libraries to
    the installation step
    """

    def run(self):
        """
        Copy libraries from the bin directory and place them as appropriate
        """

        self.announce("Moving library files", level=3)

        # We have already built the libraries in the previous build_ext step

        self.skip_build = True

        bin_dir = self.distribution.bin_dir

        libs = [os.path.join(bin_dir, _lib) for _lib in 
                os.listdir(bin_dir) if 
                os.path.isfile(os.path.join(bin_dir, _lib)) and 
                os.path.splitext(_lib)[1] in [".dll", ".so"]
                and not (_lib.startswith("python") or _lib.startswith("bpy"))]

        for lib in libs:

            shutil.move(lib, os.path.join(self.build_dir,
                                          os.path.basename(lib)))

        # Mark the libs for installation, adding them to 
        # distribution.data_files seems to ensure that setuptools' record 
        # writer appends them to installed-files.txt in the package's egg-info
        #
        # Also tried adding the libraries to the distribution.libraries list, 
        # but that never seemed to add them to the installed-files.txt in the 
        # egg-info, and the online recommendation seems to be adding libraries 
        # into eager_resources in the call to setup(), which I think puts them 
        # in data_files anyways. 
        # 
        # What is the best way?

        self.distribution.data_files = [os.path.join(self.install_dir, 
                                                     os.path.basename(lib))
                                        for lib in libs]

        # Must be forced to run after adding the libs to data_files

        self.distribution.run_command("install_data")

        super().run()

class InstallBlenderScripts(install_scripts):
    """
    Install the scripts available from the "version folder" in the build dir
    """

    def run(self):
        """
        Copy the required directory to the build directory and super().run()
        """

        self.announce("Moving scripts files", level=3)

        self.skip_build = True

        bin_dir = self.distribution.bin_dir

        scripts_dirs = [os.path.join(bin_dir, _dir) for _dir in
                        os.listdir(bin_dir) if
                        os.path.isdir(os.path.join(bin_dir, _dir))]

        for scripts_dir in scripts_dirs:

            shutil.move(scripts_dir,
                        os.path.join(self.build_dir,
                                     os.path.basename(scripts_dir)))

        # Mark the scripts for installation, adding them to 
        # distribution.scripts seems to ensure that the setuptools' record 
        # writer appends them to installed-files.txt in the package's egg-info

        self.distribution.scripts = scripts_dirs

        super().run()

class BuildCMakeExt(build_ext):
    """
    Builds using cmake instead of the python setuptools implicit build
    """

    def run(self):
        """
        Perform build_cmake before doing the 'normal' stuff
        """

        for extension in self.extensions:

            if extension.name == "bpy":

                self.build_cmake(extension)

        super().run()

    def build_cmake(self, extension: Extension):
        """
        The steps required to build the extension
        """

        # We import the setup_requires modules here because if we import them
        # at the top this script will always fail as they won't be present

        from git import Repo

        self.announce("Preparing the build environment", level=3)

        blender_dir = os.path.join(BLENDERPY_DIR, "blender")

        build_dir = pathlib.Path(self.build_temp)

        extension_path = pathlib.Path(self.get_ext_fullpath(extension.name))

        os.makedirs(blender_dir, exist_ok=True)
        os.makedirs(build_dir, exist_ok=True)
        os.makedirs(extension_path.parent.absolute(), exist_ok=True)

        # Now that the necessary directories are created, ensure that OS 
        # specific steps are performed; a good example is checking on linux 
        # that the required build libraries are in place.

        if sys.platform == "win32": # Windows only steps

            import svn.remote
            import winreg

            vs_versions = []

            for version in [12, 14, 15]:

                try:

                    winreg.OpenKey(winreg.HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT,
                                   f"VisualStudio.DTE.{version}.0")

                except:

                    pass

                else:

                    vs_versions.append(version)

            if not vs_versions:

                raise Exception("Windows users must have Visual Studio 2013 "
                                "or later installed")

            svn_lib = (f"win{'dows' if BITS == 32 else '64'}"
                       f"{'_vc12' if max(vs_versions) == 12 else '_vc14'}")
            svn_url = (f"https://svn.blender.org/svnroot/bf-blender/trunk/lib/"
                       f"{svn_lib}")
            svn_dir = os.path.join(BLENDERPY_DIR, "lib", svn_lib)

            os.makedirs(svn_dir, exist_ok=True)

            self.announce(f"Checking out svn libs from {svn_url}", level=3)

            try:

                blender_svn_repo = svn.remote.RemoteClient(svn_url)
                blender_svn_repo.checkout(svn_dir)

            except Exception as e:

                self.warn("Windows users must have the svn executable "
                          "available from the command line")
                self.warn("Please install Tortoise SVN with \"command line "
                          "client tools\" as described here")
                self.warn("https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1625406/using-"
                          "tortoisesvn-via-the-command-line")
                raise e

        elif sys.platform == "linux": # Linux only steps

            # TODO: Test linux environment, issue #1

            import apt

            apt_cache = apt.cache.Cache()

            apt_cache.update()

            # We need to re-open the apt-cache after performing the update to use the
            # Updated cache, otherwise we will still be using the old cache see: 
            # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17537390/how-to-install-a-package-using-the-python-apt-api
            apt_cache.open()

            for build_requirement in LINUX_BLENDER_BUILD_DEPENDENCIES:

                required_package = apt_cache[build_requirement]

                if not required_package.is_installed:

                    required_package.mark_install()

                    # Committing the changes to the cache could fail due to 
                    # privilages; maybe we could try-catch this exception to 
                    # elevate the privilages
                    apt_cache.commit()

                    self.announce(f"Build requirement {build_requirement} "
                                  f"installed", level=3)

            self.announce("Installing linux additional Blender build "
                          "dependencies as necessary", level=3)

            try:

                automated_deps_install_script = os.path.join(BLENDERPY_DIR, 
                                                     'blender/build_files/'
                                                     'build_environment/'
                                                     'install_deps.sh')

                self.spawn([automated_deps_install_script])

            except:

                self.warn("Could not automatically install linux additional "
                          "Blender build dependencies, attempting manual "
                          "installation")

                for addtl_requirement in LINUX_BLENDER_ADDTL_DEPENDENCIES:

                    required_package = apt_cache[addtl_requirement]

                    if not required_package.is_installed:

                        required_package.mark_install()

                        # Committing the changes to the cache could fail due to privilages
                        # Maybe we could try-catch this exception to elevate the privilages
                        apt_cache.commit()

                        self.announce(f"Additional requirement "
                                      f"{addtl_requirement} installed",
                                      level=3)

                self.announce("Blender additional dependencies installed "
                              "manually", level=3)

            else:

                self.announce("Blender additional dependencies installed "
                              "automatically", level=3)

        elif sys.platform == "darwin": # MacOS only steps

            # TODO: Test MacOS environment, issue #2

            pass

        # Perform relatively common build steps

        self.announce(f"Cloning Blender source from {BLENDER_GIT_REPO_URL}",
                      level=3)

        try:

            blender_git_repo = Repo(blender_dir)

        except:

            Repo.clone_from(BLENDER_GIT_REPO_URL, blender_dir)
            blender_git_repo = Repo(blender_dir)

        finally:

            blender_git_repo.heads.master.checkout()
            blender_git_repo.remotes.origin.pull()

        self.announce(f"Updating Blender git submodules", level=3)

        blender_git_repo.git.submodule('update', '--init', '--recursive')

        for submodule in blender_git_repo.submodules:

            submodule_repo = submodule.module()
            submodule_repo.heads.master.checkout()
            submodule_repo.remotes.origin.pull()

        self.announce("Configuring cmake project", level=3)

        self.spawn(['cmake', '-H'+blender_dir, '-B'+self.build_temp,
                    '-DWITH_PLAYER=OFF', '-DWITH_PYTHON_INSTALL=OFF',
                    '-DWITH_PYTHON_MODULE=ON',
                    f"-DCMAKE_GENERATOR_PLATFORM=x"
                    f"{'86' if BITS == 32 else '64'}"])

        self.announce("Building binaries", level=3)

        self.spawn(["cmake", "--build", self.build_temp, "--target", "INSTALL",
                    "--config", "Release"])

        # Build finished, now copy the files into the copy directory
        # The copy directory is the parent directory of the extension (.pyd)

        self.announce("Moving Blender python module", level=3)

        bin_dir = os.path.join(build_dir, 'bin', 'Release')
        self.distribution.bin_dir = bin_dir

        bpy_path = [os.path.join(bin_dir, _bpy) for _bpy in
                    os.listdir(bin_dir) if
                    os.path.isfile(os.path.join(bin_dir, _bpy)) and
                    os.path.splitext(_bpy)[0].startswith('bpy') and
                    os.path.splitext(_bpy)[1] in [".pyd", ".so"]][0]

        shutil.move(bpy_path, extension_path)

        # After build_ext is run, the following commands will run:
        # 
        # install_lib
        # install_scripts
        # 
        # These commands are subclassed above to avoid pitfalls that
        # setuptools tries to impose when installing these, as it usually
        # wants to build those libs and scripts as well or move them to a
        # different place. See comments above for additional information

setup(name='bpy',
      version='1.2.2b5',
      packages=find_packages(),
      ext_modules=[CMakeExtension(name="bpy")],
      description='Blender as a python module',
      long_description=open("./README.md", 'r').read(),
      long_description_content_type="text/markdown",
      keywords="Blender, 3D, Animation, Renderer, Rendering",
      classifiers=["Development Status :: 3 - Alpha",
                   "Environment :: Win32 (MS Windows)",
                   "Intended Audience :: Developers",
                   "License :: OSI Approved :: "
                   "GNU Lesser General Public License v3 (LGPLv3)",
                   "Natural Language :: English",
                   "Operating System :: Microsoft :: Windows :: Windows 10",
                   "Programming Language :: C",
                   "Programming Language :: C++",
                   "Programming Language :: Python",
                   "Programming Language :: Python :: 3.6",
                   "Programming Language :: Python :: Implementation :: CPython",
                   "Topic :: Artistic Software",
                   "Topic :: Education",
                   "Topic :: Multimedia",
                   "Topic :: Multimedia :: Graphics",
                   "Topic :: Multimedia :: Graphics :: 3D Modeling",
                   "Topic :: Multimedia :: Graphics :: 3D Rendering",
                   "Topic :: Games/Entertainment"],
      author='Tyler Gubala',
      author_email='gubalatyler@gmail.com',
      license='GPL-3.0',
      setup_requires=["cmake", "GitPython", 'svn;platform_system=="Windows"',
                      'apt;platform_system=="Linux"'],
      url="https://github.com/TylerGubala/blenderpy",
      cmdclass={
          'build_ext': BuildCMakeExt,
          'install_data': InstallCMakeLibsData,
          'install_lib': InstallCMakeLibs,
          'install_scripts': InstallBlenderScripts
          }
    )
```