# Python setuptools/distutils custom build for the `extra` package from GO source

Tags: python, go, installation

I am trying to create a Python package that depends on a library that is compile from Go source.

I am following the instructions specified at:
[Python setuptools/distutils custom build for the `extra` package with Makefile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41169711/python-setuptools-distutils-custom-build-for-the-extra-package-with-makefile)
The idea is to compile Go code to create the library, then provide that library to setup tools to build a Python extension.

The library is compiled from a make rule, just like in the link above.
I am getting this error when compiling:

> vendor/golang.org/x/sys/unix/syscall_linux_gc.go:10:6: missing
>   function body

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] to add meaningful code and a problem description here. Posting a [mcve] that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. Thanks!

Comment: Solved adding *.go and *.s to manifest.

Answer (score 0):

Solved adding *.go and *.s to manifest:

```
recursive-include . *.s
recursive-include . *.go
```